# Custom devise resource name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication.

I have a custom registration controller in an Api namespace, defined as follow:

```
class Api::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
end
```

My User model is defined outside the Api namespace as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end
```

In my functional tests, I put the following line in my setup so that Devise knows we work with `user` and not `api_user`:

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

It works great in my tests but I don't know how to replicate this behaviour in the real world.

The `sign_up_params` method looks for `params['api_user']` instead of `params['user']` when sanitising.

Any idea on how I could do that?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you still need a solution but I went through the same problem and just solved it :

Instead of

```
namespace :api do 
  devise_for :users
end
```

in your config/routes.rb file, just put :

```
scope :api, module: :api do 
  devise_for :users
end
```

Hope it will help other people :D